# Rejected edits history

Tags: support

I rejected an edit suggestion to that post: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/12489/49.

However, just after my click I realized that I should keep some parts of the edit, as they improve the answer (my quick reject was based on edit on a quoted material).

1. Does comment justifying the rejection reaches the editor? (If it does not, it would discourage an eager editor...)
2. Is it possible to lookup the history of rejected edits (for a particular post, or globally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [users are *not* currently notified when their suggested edits are rejected.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114094/what-happens-when-an-edit-is-rejected)  There's an ongoing [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) for that on meta.SO.

It's possible to look up a user's edit suggestion history by going to the "activity" tab on their profile and selecting "suggestions".  Clicking a particular edit will then show whether it was approved or rejected, and will also show any reasons supplied for rejecting it.

Conversely, if you want to see a list of edit suggestions you've *reviewed* recently, those can be found under "reviews" on the "activity" tab on your profile.  Alternatively, if you've *just* reviewed an edit and realize that you want to take another look at it, you may simply use your browser's back button to return to the review page.  It won't let you change your review, but it will let you see the edit and any other reviews of it, just as if you looked it up through your activity history.

If the edit suggestion was approved in any form (either as it is, or improved upon by reviewers), it will also be listed in the edit history of the post (question, answer, tag wiki, etc.) being edited.  However, edit suggestions that are simply rejected don't show up in the edit history (to normal users, anyway; they might be visible to ♦ mods).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so—I think rejected edits don't get tracked. On the other hand, if your edits are simply "rolled back," then that should be saved in the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

- I don't know if the editor receives any comment following rejection. Does someone want to experiment? (I don't think mod/highrep users edits needs to be approved).
- The list of rejected edits is available in the timeline of the post, but I don't know if it's only available to mods or also to high-rep users.